# CodeIgniter - where to put CMS

Tags: codeigniter, content-management-system, directory-structure

I come from a background of coding my client website projects from scratch with MySQL and PHP. They are typically public facing sites with a mixture of static content, dynamic content plus a little functionality here and there (i.e. account, searching etc). Nothing too heavy.

So I generally code up a little CMS site to let them update what they need to, put it in a protected folder and that's that.

Now I'd like to use CodeIgniter and more of a MVC approach for my next site. Should I be doing anything to separate the CMS out from the rest of the site or is it simply another area (with its own controllers/models etc) and extra authentication?

Answer (score 2):

There are several good methods to create an admin interface in CodeIgniter described at:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2009/07/Create-an-Admin-panel-with-CodeIgniter

You probably will want to look mostly at "#2" on his list; it's lightweight and not much additional work.

Comment: I personally do #1, and create a subdomain for the backend section. It works really well, and you can add any number of subdomains in this manner (for example, I also have an API section using the same method).

Answer (score 0):

The CMS is part of the site, if by CMS you mean administration panel / backend of your application, you can use the above link provided by coreylink as it details different ways to create an admin panel.

My personal preference is to create a folder called 'admin' in my controllers directory and create semantically meaningful names so my urls are webapp.com/admin/users and so on.